# Rellenar tabla en PHP utilizando codeigniter y recogiendo datos desde daterangepicker

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, codeigniter

Necesito poder recorrer mi tabla entre fechas elegidas por daterangepicer, así:

Por ejemplo, si elijo entre 7 días en el daterangepicker, me muestre la tabla:

- 05/04/2020
- 06/04/2020
- 07/04/2020
- 08/04/2020
- 09/04/2020
- 10/04/2020
- 11/04/2020

Y si existen los datos en la base de datos, me los muestre; si no, poder poner un input para poder introducir los datos manualmente y después, poder guardarlos en la base de datos.

Tengo por un lado la tabla en PHP en mi página de Vistas ControlHorario.php:

```
 <table class="table table-bordered" id="TablaControlHorario">
           <thead>
             <th>Fecha</th>
             <th>Entrada</th>
             <th>Salida</th>
             <th>Entrada</th>
             <th>Salida</th>
             <th>Normal</th>
             <th>Extra</th>
             <th>Formación</th>
             <th>Puesto Trabajo</th>
             <th>Acciones</th>
           </thead>
           <tbody id='BodyTablaControlHorario'>
           </tbody>
         </table>
```

Después, tengo mi controlador RRHH:

```
public function ajax()
{
        $from = $this->input->post('from');
      $to = $this->input->post('to');
      $username = $this->input->post('username_id');

      $posts = $this->RRHH_model->get_datatables($from,$to,$username);

      $data = array();
      $no = $this->input->post('start');
      foreach ($posts as $post)
      {

          $no++;
          $row = array();
          $row[] = $post->$fecha;
          $row[] = $post->id_usuario;
          $row[] = $post->entrada1;
          $row[] = $post->salida1;
          $row[] = $post->entrada2;
          $row[] = $post->salida2;
          $row[] = $post->hora_normal;
          $row[] = $post->hora_extra;
          $row[] = $post->hora_formacion;
          $row[] = $post->puesto_trabajo;

          $data[] = $row;
      }

      $output = array(
          "draw" => $this->input->post('draw'),
          "recordsTotal" => $this->RRHH_model->count_all(),
          "recordsFiltered" => $this->RRHH_model->count_filtered($from,$to,$username),
          "data" => $data,
      );
      //output to json format
      echo json_encode($output);
}
```

}

Y el modelo RRHH_model:

```php
    <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class RRHH_model extends MY_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

        var $table = 'controlhorariointernos';
    var $select = array('id','id_usuario','fecha','entrada1','salida1','entrada2','salida2','hora_normal','hora_extra','hora_formacion','puesto_trabajo');
        //var $column_order = array('id','title','body','created_at'); //set column field database for datatable orderable
    //var $column_search = array('id','title','body','created_at'); //set column field database for datatable searchable
    var $order = array('fecha' => 'asc'); // default order

    public function get_datatables($from, $to, $username)
    {
        $this->_get_datatables_query($from, $to, $username);

        if($_POST['length'] != -1)
            $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);

        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result();
    }

    public function count_filtered($from, $to, $username)
    {
        $this->_get_datatables_query($from, $to, $username);

        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->num_rows();
    }

    public function count_all()
    {
        $this->db->from($this->table);

        return $this->db->count_all_results();
    }

    private function _get_datatables_query($from,$to,$username)
    {

        $this->db
             ->select($this->select)
             ->from($this->table);

        if($from!='' && $to!='' || $from!= NULL) // To process our custom input parameter
        {

            $this->db->where('fecha BETWEEN "'. $from . '" and "'. $to .'" and id_usuario = "' . $username .'"');
        }

        $i = 0;
        foreach ($this->column_search as $item) // loop column
        {
            if($_POST['search']['value']) // if datatable send POST for search
            {

                if($i===0) // first loop
                {
                    $this->db->group_start(); // open bracket. query Where with OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with other WHERE with AND.
                    $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                }

                if(count($this->column_search) - 1 == $i) //last loop
                    $this->db->group_end(); //close bracket
            }
            $i++;
        }

        if(isset($_POST['order'])) // here order processing
        {
            $this->db->order_by($this->column_order[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);

        }
        elseif (isset($this->order)) // default order processing
        {
            $order = $this->order;

            $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
        }
    }
}
```